# Correct Syntax to Add ORDER BY to SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

How can I add `ORDER BY field` to the end of this SQL query 
`$sql = "SELECT item_id,field FROM item WHERE department=".$catid;`? I can't get the syntax right due to the PHP variable at the end...

I tried `$sql = "SELECT item_id,field FROM item WHERE department=".$catid ORDER BY field;` but obviously that didn't work

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Variables don't go in SQL, parameterize your query.

Comment: `ORDER BY field` is an obvious syntax error. Are you using error reporting? It is the same as you wrote your other string encapsulation, `"SELECT ...` BUT realllly you shouldn't be doing this at all. The query should be `SELECT item_id,field FROM item WHERE department= ? ORDER BY field` then bind `$catid`.

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry, I don't know much more SQL... What would be the best practice way of doing this?

Comment: It's PHP syntax, not SQL. The SQL is "right" if `$catid` is an integer.

Comment: I don't know what driver your using with PHP so I can't tell you but look up `prepared statements` with the driver you are using.

Comment: I was just posting an answer to the question you just deleted...

Comment: @Nick My apologies, deleted the wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your syntax error like this, using another concatenation operator `.` to append the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_id,field FROM item WHERE department=".$catid." ORDER BY field";
```

As long as `$catid` is an integer, that will work, but it may leave you open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1), dependent on the source of the value in `$catid`.

Best practice is to use a prepared query. For `MySQLi`, something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_id,field FROM item WHERE department=? ORDER BY field";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $catid);  // change to 's' if $catid is a string
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with results
}
```